# How to test the significance of coefficients, with taking consideration of the autocorrelation in residuals?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, residuals, heteroscedasticity, linear

I am running a linear regression. After use DWtest, I can realize that there is autocorrelation in the residuals. I am wondering, is there any test I can use to test the significance of coefficients, with taking consideration of the autocorrelation?

For instance, when I test the Homoscedasticity, I can use the white test to take consideration of the effect of the heteroscedasticity on the linear regression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the residuals are autocorrelated, your SEs will be biased. Depending on the source of the autocorrelation, you can likely build it into your model - e.g., using generalized least squares you can build in spatial or temporal autocorrelation pretty simply. If you're using R, `gls` in the `nlme` package is your go-to, and take a look at the variety of autocorrelation structures you can use. Zuur et al.'s book on mixed models has some nice sections on this.